# Read file line by line through shell script in a Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I've got a `Makefile` with the following script:

```
target: test.py
    $(PYTHON) test.py
```

The script `test.py` writes the test results on to a file named as `test_result.txt` with test statistics, example:

```
Number of tests:
Total  : 14
Passed : 14
Failed : 0
```

On the call is made to test.py in make, I want to read `test_result.txt` line by line and echo it. When the line starts with Failed, I wish to read the value and if it is greater than 0 then I return false which would stop the build.

Note: I know to write this in shell script, but when I tried it there were some conflict between the $ symbol of make and shell. Not sure how to resolve it. 
Couple of example scripts I tried:

```
1. while read line; do echo -e "$line\n"; done < test_results.txt
2. cat test/test_results.txt | while read line; echo "$line\n"; done;
```

For both scripts the output was `ine` for the total number of lines in the file. 
Though the cat command worked and displayed all the contents in the file.

Comment: You need to double `$` in a recipe to get it to the shell. So `echo "$$line\n"` (though the `\n` there isn't necessary). Also you don't need to read the file line-by-line to display it, just `cat` it and you'll get it all (then read just the last line, or whatever, for the `Failed` count). Alternatively have `test.py` return non-zero for failed tests and catch and re-exit with that value after displaying the test output (or give `test.py` an option to write to file *and* standard output).

Comment: The doubling thing is mentioned in the [Using Variables in Recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-in-Recipes) section of the GNU Make Manual.

Comment: @EtanReisner I added $$line, still I got an error: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: @EtanReisner But the first script worked perfectly once the $$ symbol was added. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You missed `do` on the second version. And as written those two lines are  what? Double spacing the output?

Comment: Gotcha... And I did write only one.